# C Program - I can't run a shell script in the background

Tags: c, shell

I'm new to programming and I need to run a shell script in the background with C program, here's what I've tried:

```
system('sh /path/to/my/program start > /dev/null &');
```

The problem is that the script won't run in the background, it's find thought if I get rid of the `&`. How should I do this?

Comment: simple quotes aren't going to work very well. Don't you have any warnings with that?

Comment: try `system("sh /path/to/my/program start > /dev/null &");`

Comment: "the script won't run in the background". So what is the result? Compile error? Crash? Doesn't run at all? Runs but not in the background? Please be specific.

Answer (score 0):

The Linux manual for [system()](https://linux.die.net/man/3/system) says:

> `system()` executes a command specified in command by calling /bin/sh -c command, **and returns after the command has been completed**.

So, it is not expected to run in the background.

Answer (score 0):

You should 'fork' your process to 'system' your batch...